# Get location from search/tweets using Twitter API 1.1

Tags: php, twitter

After following a tutorial I am able to retrieve tweets using PHP. But the tutorial only showed how to display the name and text. I am now trying to display the geolocation(lat and lng) attached to the tweets. I checked at the sample JSON showed at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/search/tweets to see how to do that. I am trying with the below code.

```
$results = $toa->get('search/tweets', $query);
foreach ($results->statuses as $result) {
if(!($result->geo===null)){
echo "$result->user->screen_name ."<br/>". $result->text . "<br/>".$result->geo;
}
}
```

But I am getting the below error

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
```

on the line of $result->geo.
How should I use $result->geo to print the lat and lng. Or is it any other attribute that I should use to get location coordinates?

I tried with $result->user->location but I'm not sure if that is the location from which the tweet was sent or the location in user's bio information. I think its the bio information. I need the location from which the tweet was posted.

Comment: Does it give you a line number or a stack trace where the error occurs? Also, you could attempt doing a `var_dump()` on the `$result->geo` to see what is returned.

Comment: Yes, the line number shows the line with $result->geo is cause.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Twitter API, do you know what type of object is being returned as geo? Also, have you tried to `var_dump($result->geo)` as mentioned before?